# OpenLayers: Create button to check/ uncheck all layers

Tags: openlayers

Has anyone create, or know how one might go about creating an openlayer map with a button to check/uncheck all overlays?

I have a map with several overlays, and it would be make it easier for the user to be able to uncheck all layers at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `hideAllOverlays` and `showAllOverlays` from your button callback.

```
// UNTESTED
function setAllOverlaysVisibility(map, status) {
   var layers = map.layers;
   for (var i = 0; i<layers.length; ++i) {
        var layer = layers[i];
        if (!layer.isBaseLayer) {
           layer.setVisiblity(status);
        }
   }
}

function hideAllOverlays(map) {
   setAllOverlaysVisibility(map, false);
}

function showAllOverlays(map) {
   setAllOverlaysVisibility(map, true);
}
```